# Find $h(x)=[1,4[$

Tags: functions, inverse-function

**Let $f: \mathbb R \longrightarrow  \mathbb R$ and $g: \mathbb R \longrightarrow  \mathbb R$ given by
$$f(x)=x^2 \quad \text{and} \quad g(x)=x+5$$
Consider the function $$h: \mathbb R \longrightarrow  \mathbb R$$ given by $h(x)=f \circ g$. What is the ur $h^{-1}([1,4[)$ ?**

The equation I have to solve is $h(x)=[1,4[$. I do not know how to solve it analytically so I tried to solve the problem by drawing.

Q1: $h(x)$ is a number but $[1,4[$ is an interval (set). How can I make sense of this equation? A number and a set can never be the same.

Q2: What theorems, definitions etc. should I use to solve it analytically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $x\in\mathbb R$,\begin{align}x\in h^{-1}\bigl([1,4)\bigr)&\iff h(x)\in[1,4)\\&\iff(x+5)^2\in[1,4)\\&\iff x+5\in[1,2)\text{ or }x+5\in(-2,-1]\\&\iff x\in[-4,-3)\text{ or }x\in(-7,-6].\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But It's not clear for me what is happening after the third bi-implication?

Comment: I am just using the fact that$$1\leqslant a^2<4\iff -2<a\leqslant1\text{ or }1\leqslant a<2.$$Note that the square roots of $1$ are $\pm1$ and that the square roots of $4$ are $\pm2$.

Comment: Okay, I understand.

Answer (score 2):

$h = f \circ g$, so $h^{-1} = g^{-1} \circ f^{-1}$.  Then \begin{align*}
h^{-1}([1,4[) &= g^{-1} \circ f^{-1}([1,4[)  \\
    &= g^{-1}(]-2,-1] \cup [1,2[)  \\
    &= ]-7,-6] \cup [-4,-3[  \text{.}
\end{align*}